# Gstreamer Write to Pipeline in Opencv Silently Dies

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to write to a gstreamer pipeline from within opencv (c++). I have it all set up, but when I run the program there is no output, no errors, no indication at all that it is even in the code. It just doesn't do anything. I have tried using "-vvv" so it will display what it is up to, with no result. Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"


#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{


    const char* right_cam_gst = "nvcamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),\
                                              width=(int)640,\
                                              height=(int)360,\
                                              format=(string)I420,\
                                              framerate=(fraction)10/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw,\
                                              format=(string)I420 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,\
                                              format=(string)BGR ! appsink";


    VideoCapture capture(right_cam_gst); // open the default camera
    if(!capture.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    VideoWriter writer;
    writer.open("-vvv appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink -vvv host=127.0.0.1 port=5000",  0, (double)10, Size(640, 360), true);


    Mat distCoeffs;
    Mat intrinsic;

    cv::FileStorage storage("CamData.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
    storage["distCoeffs"] >> distCoeffs;
    storage["intrinsic"] >> intrinsic;
    storage.release();




    Mat image;
    Mat imageUndistorted;

    while(1)
    {
        capture >> image;
        undistort(image, imageUndistorted, intrinsic, distCoeffs);
        writer << imageUndistorted;

       // imshow("win1", image);
        imshow("win2", imageUndistorted);
        waitKey(1);
    }

        capture.release();

    return 0;
}
```

pretty simple. It grabs a video, undistorts it, and prints it to both imwrite and the gstreamer pipeline (video is displayed with imwrite). I can use the shell command: `nc -l 5000 -u` to find that there is absolutely no data on port 5000. But if I run:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

Then the shell command displays data on the port. What is the next step to diagnose the problem? Thanks!

**System: Nvidia Jetson TX1**

Comment: Just found the argument: ! fakesink dump=TRUE !    

So now with the pipe: -vvv appsrc ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! fakesink dump=TRUE 
I am getting data through. Stil get nothing with udp though...

Comment: I've question maybe it is related to what you're doing. I want to know what filters are applying to the frames and what image processing is done. I posted a question if you want more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848575/gstreamer-and-frame-image-processing-filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it looks like the issue was in the caps. This one works well with VLC:

```
-vvv appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=360, format=I420 ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=199.58.96.228 port=5000
```

For anyone else trying to diagnose the issue with their gstream, here are some tips:

Use `! fakesink dump=TRUE !` to see if data is getting to that point in the pipe.

Start with a simple pipe like `appsrc ! fakesink dump=TRUE`. If you get data in the console, you know that appsrc is getting data. Then move on to something a little longer like:

```
appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=360, format=I420 ! fakesink dump=TRUE
```

All this will do is convert the video and print it. If you still have data, then it converted correctly and you can move on. If not, make sure you have the right format, resolution ect.

Continue adding elements and testing them untill the stream is converted correctly. THEN you can add the udpsink.

Hope this helps!